# Aurora Natalis or Aurora Natalicus?

Tags: vocabulary, adjective, word-choice, christianity

I have practically no experience with Latin, but from what I understand *Aurora Borealis* roughly means northern dawn, and *Aurora Australis* roughly means southern dawn. What would be the equivalent way to say Christmas dawn? Would it be either *Aurora Natalis* or *Aurora Natalicus*, or am I way off the mark.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is an interesting question. If you join this SE site, you will have a better access to this question and will gain reputation from it. For the record: Translation requests are considered off-topic unless they show your own attempts, but your attempts are very good. See [this meta page](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/q/143/79) for a guide to asking such questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are referring to a Christian concept (at least in its origin) I don't see any harm in using Ecclesiastical Latin. I would thus suggest:

> **Aurora Nativitatis**

Ecclesiastical Latin has a number of ways to say *Christmas*. Both *natalis, -is* and [*nativitas, -atis*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnativitas) are used to form most of the names (e.g. Nativitas Domini).

Both words exist in Classical Latin, but of course in a broader meaning of *birth* in general.

In liturgy, ***Nativitas*** is preferred, and sometimes used without modifiers to refer to Christmas, since other uses are somehow more specific (e.g. in *Nativitas Beatae Mariae Virginis*). Hence tempus Nativitatis, octava Nativitatis (Christmas time, Christmas octave). See e.g., the current General Instruction of the Roman Missal [in Latin](https://www.ewtn.com/library/CURIA/cdwlgrm.htm) (a quite central, official document for Catholic Liturgy), that uses *Nativitas Domini* as well as *Nativitas* alone.

Since *Christmas* modifies *Dawn* (the dawn somehow *belongs* to Christmas day, and you could also say *the dawn of Christmas [day]*), it is necessary to use the genitive form of *Nativitas* (i.e. *Nativitatis*).

Comment: I immediately thought of *nativitas* too. This is used throughout the Middle Ages to refer to the birth of Christ in dates, as in *anno MCXXo post nativitatem (Domini)* in secular documents, and also to refer to days before or after Christmas, as in *feria secunda post nativitatem Domini*. If *aurora* can be used with a genitive to indicate "the morning after", then I agree with Rafael. Otherwise I would use *post nativitatem*. At any rate, I would certainly use this word.

Answer (score 5):

*Aurora borealis/australis* indeed means "northern/southern dawn".
To convert this to a Christmas dawn, we need a Latin adjective meaning "Christams-related".

Latin does not have a nice word for "Christmas" (or a related adjective) the way many modern European languages do.
*Natalis* and *natalicius* both mean "birthday-related".
The reason why words of this kind are associated with Christmas is that it is the Christ's birthday, *dies natalis Christi*.
It depends on context whether confusion between birthday and Christmas is possible.

While *natalicius* means "birthday-related" in general, my feeling is that it is more commonly used for Christmas than *natalis*.
Therefore *natalicius* is the adjective I suggest.
Since *aurora* is feminine, we need to put it in feminine form: *natalicia*.
Therefore my suggestion is ***aurora natalicia***.

I would interpret *aurora natalicia* primarily as "Christmas dawn" and *aurora natalis* as "birthday dawn", but it may be a matter of taste.
Be aware that both mean both.
If you want to be more verbose, you can always be explicit: *aurora diei natalis Christi* is "the dawn of the Christ's birthday".

Comment: Since we are speaking about a religious concept, I don't see any harm in using church Latin. In it, the proper noun _Nativitas, -atis_ (without modifiers) has the specialized meaning of Christmas. Hence: aurora nativitatis.

Comment: @Rafael, I must confess I had never heard of *Nativitas* before. While I agree that it would probably be a good translation, I think it would not be understood by as many Latinists. (But I have been wrong before...) You can also make that into a separate answer. A church Latin point of view would be nice.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thank you, that is extremely helpful. One last question, am I correct it would be pronounced roughly nah-tah-li-chi-ah?

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom, you are welcome! That is one possible pronunciation. Latin pronunciation varies greatly between different times and places, and there is no single correct way. (If you want more details on pronunciation options, I suggest asking a separate question.)